# is it possible to sing whispering?

Tags: practice

I would like to sing but my parents are strictly always with me, at home... And I would like to sing without being eared by my parents. They are devil. I don't want. I have to sing notes that my parents don't ear. How to sing whispering ? is it possible ?

Comment: Sing in the shower, in the bathroom. Surely they're not with you then?

Comment: Your parents should be happy to have a child that loves to sing! Say them “hello” from me. ;)

Comment: Please note that a) this might not be effective, since whispering can actually louder and more audible than a soft voice, and b) prolonged periods of whispering may be harmful to your voice (medical science is currently undecided about that).

Comment: Hi,  we are quite sympathetic to your plight.  Please provide more information: what is your age, what country, and is your parents' dislike in any way religion-related?  This really is more of a question for "interpersonal relationships" StackExchange site as it stands.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't sound like they are banning you from singing, but that you are scared to perform to an audience - even one merely perceived to be within earshot.

If you want to keep on singing, that's certainly something you need to put behind you sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 1):

I’m always singing, whistling, humming (in the supermarket, at the beach, when walking, biking, or when I have to wait  in a queue ... never mind what other say. But when I’m writing music I’m a kind of whistling and whispering.

If you want to practice your voice (sonority, resonance, breathing, articulation, volume, vibrato etc, you have to sing a loud. But all other aspects (lyrics, ear training, intervals, sheet reading etc) you can practice muted, whispering, or even mental training.

If you live in a flat or in an apartment with a few rooms and thin walls it can be really boring and nerving if you always sing load.

My wife also was sick of me farting around, especially when we were in the open air. But I’d say she is an angel!